# Using "to be" before a Name?

Tags: grammar

My sister got this task for her homework and there is this particular bit 
"Also the famous waltzes is Frederic Chopin. These works give some sadness. Probably he was very sad because he could not come home at the end of his life." 
I mean, I don't even wanna start on "the" before plurals, but maybe it's just a next level grammar that I don't familiar with? 
Here's a full text in case you're wondering. Maybe you'll spot a few more

Classical music

Classical music is often associated with the music of the past. Classical music means music produced in the Western world between 1750 and 1820. This music includes opera, chamber music, choral pieces, and music a full orchestra.

Currently, scientists proved that listening to classical music has a beneficial effect on the physical and the moral state of a man. This music always makes you to have emotions or associations, as though reading a good book and, together with its heroes live among them. Classical music also enhances the memory of a man.

Classical music in its limited definition includes the works of Wolfgang Mozart and Ludwig van Beethoven.

Henry Percell’s wrote the first British classical opera Dido and Aeneas. Several bars from his song Lilliburlero are used by the BBC as a signature tune.

Benjamin Britten was a master of vocal music of all kinds. Britten started the Aldeburgh Festival. Benjamin Britten began writing music as a child. Later he wrote deal of music for young people.

Also the famous waltzes is Frederic Chopin. These works give some sadness. Probably he was very sad because he could not come home at the end of his life.

Classical music may also refer to the native and folk music of any country. The styles vary greatly depending upon available instruments. This style also includes music being written now, and we may speak of modern classical music.

Comment: It's not correct. That sentence is incomplete. Seemingly the idea is to continue the previous ideas while mentioning Chopin. So "also the famous waltzes of Frederic Chopin" is better or "by Frederic Chopin" is another choice. Or invert the sentence with "Frederic Chopin, another classical composer also wrote famous waltzes..." But the sentence needs to be a whole statement.

Comment: The entire passage is rife with errors.  One error is the spelling of *Purcell.*  Is the assignment to correct the errors?  What is your question?

Comment: @phoog no! The assignment is TO TRANSLATE THEM :) have you spot more in the text itself?

Comment: To translate them to what language?  Or from?  If the latter, without knowing the source text it would be impossible to correct all the errors or be certain of having identified them all.

Comment: @Hunter yeah, that's what I thought, appreciate 

Comment: @phoog Russian. I believe that her teacher is just doesn't capable of doing his work tbh. This is a text that he whore, just so you know.

Comment: Sorry, is she supposed to translate this to Russian or has she translated it from Russian?

Comment: @phoog she suppose to translate it to Russian. The text was given and written by her teacher. Sorry, forgot to mention that

Comment: It is written in very poor English, and some of the statements are dubious too.